# How to schedule a jenkins job trough url?

Tags: php, jenkins

I'm implementing a way to trigger jenkins jobs and to schedule them with php in my site. The way I'm doing the "on-the-fly" trigger is by simply calling the url of the job with some parameters (I'm also using [Build Token Root Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Token+Root+Plugin) so I can trigger the jobs without authentication).

Example below:

```
$data = array(
  'job' => 'JOB NAME',
  'token' => 'job_token',
  'parameter1' => 'some parameter',
);

$options = array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  'data' => drupal_http_build_query($data),
  'timeout' => 15,
  'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
);

drupal_http_request('http://localhost:8080/buildByToken/buildWithParameters', $options);
```

I can trigger the job with multiple parameters but I need to schedule the build. In jenkins there is this option "Build periodically" but it's not a parameter.

Anyone knows a way to schedule the job trough the url way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `?delay=300secs` to the end of the URL to schedule the job to start in five minutes.

Note that `sec` and `secs` are currently the only [accepted duration units](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/98a6c6f/core/src/main/java/jenkins/util/TimeDuration.java#L41-L43).

Comment: That's great Christopher! Thanks!

Comment: Btw, I know I can pass parameters that I define in my jobs but I'm assuming this delay is a built in one. With that in mind, is there a list of those build in parameters that I can consult? Thanks.

Comment: There are no other built-in parameters, at least not for this plugin. This `delay` parameter is the same as you'll see in any "Build Now" URL.